# window.location safari jquery issue (doesnt open href link)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, safari

I have a small problem with safari and window.location. I have a link in my wordpress code, which should do two things:

1. open the href in a new tab
2. reload the current page and add ?=clicked to the URL

this works good so far in chrome and firefox, but on safar (desktop) and iPhone it doesnt :-( It just reloads the page... and i have to click 2-3x times very fast to make the href link open the target page.

**this my link code:**

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url(the_field('acf_custom_field')); ?>" target="_blank" class="goout" data-permalink="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>/?=clicked">BUTTON NAME</a>
```

**this is my jquery:**

```
$(".goout").on('click', function() {
    var ctalink = $(this).attr('data-permalink');
    window.location).attr('href', ctalink);
});
```

how can I fix this in safari?

Comment: `window.location)` starts things off with a typo (that stray `)`), then adds `.attr()` (a jQuery method, not available on window.location). Instead, just say `window.location.href = ctalink;`.

Comment: thank you for your answer paul. I've changed it to your solution, but safari behaves the same :-(